# How to get user input in Unix C?

Tags: c, unix

I'm trying to code a program that can be used in the Unix environment.  However, this is my first time doing such a thing and I'm confused regarding some things. My code is as follows:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define BUFFSIZE 4096

int main (int argc, char * argv[]){

int n;
char buf[BUFFSIZE];

if (argc != 2){
    err_sys("usage a.out <pathname>");  
}

if (access(argv[1], R_OK) == -1){
    err_ret("access error for %s", argv[1]);
}

if (access(argv[2], R_OK) == 0){
    printf("Would you like to overwrite (Y or N)? \n");
    if(){
        exit(0);
    }
}

while ((n = read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, BUFFSIZE) > 0)){
    if (write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, n) != n){
        err_sys("write error"); 
    }
}

if (n < 0){
    err_sys("read error");
}

close(STDOUT_FILENO);
close(STDIN_FILENO);

exit(0);

}
```

Okay, so basically, I have to write a program that uses open, read, write, close, and access.  However, I'm completely confused on how to implement the part where I have to prompt the user to overwrite or not if the second argument (which is a file name) is already in place.

Aka these lines of code:

```
if (access(argv[2], R_OK) == 0){
   printf("Would you like to overwrite (Y or N)? \n");
       if(){
           exit(0);
}
```

I'm not exactly sure how to get the response from the user and what the condition would be.

Also, if any of my other code is wrong, feel free to inform me and let me know how I can improve it.

Thank you!

Just added:

```
if (open(argv[1], O_RDONLY) < 0){
    err_ret("open error for %s", argv[1]);
}
```

Comment: Do you have a `getch()` implemented?

Comment: Nowhere in my code do I have a getch() implemented.  I just started programming in the Unix environment less than 2 weeks ago so I don't know that much.  I just know that this part should look somewhat like cp -i if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Please make sure to ask the "real question", which appears to be "how to get user input", and reflect it in the title. If there are other questions, ask them separately. For a general "code review", try a code review site.

Comment: This line of code is incorrectly parenthesized: `while ((n = read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, BUFFSIZE) > 0)){` ... it sets n to 0 or 1. (The second error of this type posted to [c] today.)

Comment: At some point, you need to open the input file and the output file (and they won't be on the STDIN_FILENO and STDOUT_FILENO descriptors unless you do some more work before calling `open()`).  And you should close those descriptors, rather than the standard ones, at the end.  You need `<fcntl.h>` to declare `open()`.  You need `<stdlib.h>` to declare `exit()`, though I'd rather you just wrote `return` instead of `exit()` at the end of `main()` — not everyone agrees.  You haven't declared `err_sys()` and `err_ret()`, either.

Comment: I've actually been working on this the whole time you guys have been posting and I didn't realize anyone else posted, lolz.  I added in fcntl.h and included apue.h (included with my programming book) so that I can use err_sys and err_ret.  I'm in the process of adding the opens now.

Comment: Ah - Stevens; good book.

Comment: It's helped me understand unix programming so much in just a matter of 2 weeks so far.  Super excited to get more into it.

Answer (score 0):

To read only one char, you can call getchar() (stdio.h) (there is scanf() too).

Sample:

`c = getchar();

if(c == 'Y' || c == 'y'){ ... }

else if(c == 'N' || c == 'n'){ ... }

else { printf("Wrong option!") }`

Comment: Alright, so I got the program to actually compile now so thank you for that.  The only issue is that I'm now getting two warnings for these lines saying "comparison between pointer and integer [enabled by default]"

Comment: @Requiem `c` should be declared `int`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use getchar() or scanf() to get user input.

Answer (score 0):

Use fgets(3) or readline(3), they are generic enough to be used in many different scenarios.  Avoid using scanf(3) as it has issues, more info [here](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html)

On a side note, please use 'size_t n' instead of 'int n'.  In general you can just use BUFSIZ which is an implementation defined value and readily available in the headers.  Also, why do you close the stdin and stdout on exit?  There is no specific reason to do that in your program.

Comment: I am required to close the files before exiting out of the program.